# Html helper method not outputting results in mvc view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My helper looks like:

```
public static string OutputBlah( this HtmlHelper helper )
{

 return htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
}
```

then in my viewpage:

```
<%= MyHelpers.OutputBlah() %>
```

Should this be working or am I missing something?
Error says that there is no overload that accepts 0 arguements.

What should I be passing into my method in the viewpage?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to call an extension method by using a static method call. You can change your code to be

```
<%= MyHelpers.OutputBlah(Html) %>
```

But you should probably change it to use it like a proper extension method:

```
<%= Html.OputputBlah() %>
```

In order to do this, you need to <%@ Import Namespace="YourHelperNameSpace" %> at the top of the page. Or add it to web.config  node.

Answer (score 0):

What does the class declaration look like? Make sure you have made the class itself `static` as well:

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
    public static string OutputBlah(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then use the regular `Html` property of type `HtmlHelper` in the `View`:

```
<%= Html.OutputBlah() %>
```

---

Answer to follow-up question from OP:

When declaring a method like this (`static` method in `static class`, and with the first parameter with the `this` keyword), you define an [*Extension Method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) - a feature that was introduced in C# 3.0. The basic idea is that you define a method that is hooked into another class, thus *extending* it.

In this case, you're extending the `HtmlHelper` class (becuase that is the type of the `this` parameter), and thereby making `.OutputBlah()` available on any instance of `HtmlHelper`. If you examine the [`Html`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.html.aspx) property of the [`ViewPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.aspx), you'll notice that it is in fact of type `HtmlHelper`.
So when you use `Html.OutputBlah()` in your view, you're actually accessing the `HtmlHelper` instance contained in the viewpage's `Html` property, and calling your own extension method on it.

Comment: How will it be available under "Html." when it is my MyHelpers class?

Comment: Because you have written an "extension method" which is new to C# 3.0. You specified the method as an extension method by placing "this" keyword in the first method parameter. There are tons of tutorials if you want to search for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flush the HTML writer. I'm almost sure this is it.

Edit: Plese ignore - I missread the original question.